# Tableau Integration with Web project

Tags: javascript, java, tableau-api

I am doing Tableau integration with web project using java script api. I have configured my ip in tableau server using  commnad :tabadmin set wgserver.trusted_hosts "" and respective commands .But I am not able to get the ticket, ended up with -1. I have followed all configuration steps.

```
 public class TableauServlet extends javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public TableauServlet() {
    super();
}       

protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    final String user = "raghu";
    final String wgserver = "103.xxx.xxx.xx";
    final String dst = "views/Regional/College?:iid=1";
    final String params = ":embed=yes&:toolbar=yes";

    String ticket = getTrustedTicket(wgserver, user, request.getRemoteAddr());

    if ( !ticket.equals("-1") ) {
        response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_MOVED_TEMPORARILY);
        response.setHeader("Location", "http://" + wgserver + "/trusted/" + ticket + "/" + dst + "?" + params);
    }
    else
        // handle error
        throw new ServletException("Invalid ticket " + ticket);
}   

// the client_ip parameter isn't necessary to send in the POST unless you have
// wgserver.extended_trusted_ip_checking enabled (it's disabled by default)
private String getTrustedTicket(String wgserver, String user, String remoteAddr) 
    throws ServletException 
{
    OutputStreamWriter out = null;
    BufferedReader in = null;
    try {
        // Encode the parameters
        StringBuffer data = new StringBuffer();
        data.append(URLEncoder.encode("username", "UTF-8"));
        data.append("=");
        data.append(URLEncoder.encode(user, "UTF-8"));
        data.append("&");
        data.append(URLEncoder.encode("client_ip", "UTF-8"));
        data.append("=");
        data.append(URLEncoder.encode(remoteAddr, "UTF-8"));

        // Send the request
        URL url = new URL("http://" + wgserver + "/trusted");
        URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        out = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
        out.write(data.toString());
        out.flush();

        // Read the response
        StringBuffer rsp = new StringBuffer();
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
        String line;
        while ( (line = in.readLine()) != null) {
            rsp.append(line);
        }

        return rsp.toString();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new ServletException(e);
    }
    finally {
        try {
            if (in != null) in.close();
            if (out != null) out.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {}
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing 'target_site' parameter in your URL where you get trusted ticket, its needed if you don't have the 'views/Regional/College' in your default site.

I had gone through a lot of frustration with the '-1' ticket too! 
One thing you might try is restarting the tableau server after you have added your web server IP to the trusted_hosts of tableau.

Another thing we ended up doing was adding both the internal ip and external ip of the web server to trusted_hosts on tableau. Since you are using 103.xxx.xxx.xx as your tableau server I am assuming both servers live on the same internal network. You might try that if everything else fails.

My code is almost exactly same as yours and works fine. So if your problem persists, it must be something related to configuration.
here is my code:

```
private String getAuthenticationTicket(String tableauServerUserName,String tableauServerUrl, String targetSite) {

        OutputStreamWriter out = null;
        BufferedReader in = null;
        try {
            StringBuffer data = new StringBuffer();
            data.append(URLEncoder.encode("username", Constant.UTF_8));
            data.append("=");
            data.append(URLEncoder.encode(tableauServerUserName, Constant.UTF_8));
            data.append("&");
            data.append(URLEncoder.encode("target_site", Constant.UTF_8));
            data.append("=");
            data.append(URLEncoder.encode(targetSite, Constant.UTF_8));
            URL url = new URL(tableauServerUrl + "/" + "trusted");

            URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            out = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
            out.write(data.toString());
            out.flush();
            StringBuffer rsp = new StringBuffer();
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
            String line;
            while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                rsp.append(line);
            }
            return rsp.toString();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            //log stuff, handle error
            return null;
        } finally {
            try {
                if (in != null)
                    in.close();
                if (out != null)
                    out.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
               //log stuff, handle error
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your Reply @merawalaid. I have set the target parameter now im getting html page as ticket like {<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><meta charset="UTF-8"><title>Tableau Server Sign In</title><script src="/console-polyfill.js?3e2ck308xtv86w29"></script> }and now problem is org.apache.coyote.http11.HeadersTooLargeException: An attempt was made to write more data to the response headers than there was room available in the buffer. Increase maxHttpHeaderSize on the connector or write less data into the response headers.

Comment: Humm... so it looks like Tableau server didn't give you a trusted token and is trying to redirect you to its login page. If I was in ur place i would just get rid of 'client_ip' for now until i have the basic token mechanism working. Also I would check if user 'raghu' has access configured on tableau server to the 'target_site' you specified. From code perspective I can't find anything wrong with what your are doing, I have very similar code working. So the problem must be because of some configuration issue.

Comment: one thing i forgot to mention is tableau server is on some other network and webserver is in my local.Im trying to access tableau server from my local.Is there any redirect facility?

Comment: can you paste sample code which you have.I have checked all configurations still not able to find it.Thanks alot for your help